# widthDetails() on a text grob doesn't pay attention to font size - workaround?

Tags: r, r-grid

The [`widthDetails`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/widthDetails.html) grid utility, when applied to text grobs, does not appear to pay attention to the font size.

```
> version$version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)"
> library(grid)
> widthDetails(textGrob(label="abcdef", gp=gpar(fontsize=12)))
[1] 0.5inches
> widthDetails(textGrob(label="abcdef", gp=gpar(fontsize=8.8)))
[1] 0.5inches
```

Indeed, inspecting the (exposed part of the) code, it looks like it ignores the per-grob graphics parameters entirely.

```
> grid:::widthDetails.text
function (x) 
{
    bounds <- grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), 
        x$x, x$y, resolveHJust(x$just, x$hjust), resolveVJust(x$just, 
            x$vjust), x$rot, 0)
    if (is.null(bounds)) 
        unit(0, "inches")
    else unit(bounds[3L], "inches")
}
<bytecode: 0x49eab10>
<environment: namespace:grid>
```

I am inclined to say this is just a plain old bug, but can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I still think this counts as a bug in grid, and I'm going to leave this open for other answers, but a sufficient-for-me workaround is to push a viewport with the grob's graphics parameters.

```
widthDetailsWithGP <- function (grob) {
    if (!is.null(grob$gp)) {
        pushViewport(viewport(gp=grob$gp))
        on.exit(popViewport())
    }
    return(widthDetails(grob))
}
```

It might conceivably also be necessary to push `grob$vp` if present; I don't understand what that's for, and it always seems to be null in the situations I care about.